# To find the general integral of quasilinear P.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general integral of the partial differential equation.

$2x(y+z^2)p+y(2y+z^2)q=z^3$

Clearly the Lagrange's auxillary equations are

$\frac{dx}{P}     = \frac{dy}{Q}. =\frac{dz}{R}$

Where P=$2x(y+z^2)$ ,Q=$y(2y+z^2)$ & R=$z^3$

on comparing the given P.D.E with 
the general quasilinear equation 
P(x,y,z) p+Q(x,y,z)q=R(x,y,z)

I should get F($\frac{x}{yz}, \frac{z^2-2y}{yz}$)=0 as the general integral but unable to detect how should I use the auxillary equations to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $\quad\frac{dx}{P} = \frac{dy}{Q} =\frac{dz}{R}\quad$ it is more clear to write explicitly the equations :
$$\frac{dx}{2x(y+z^2)} = \frac{dy}{y(2y+z^2)} =\frac{dz}{z^3}$$
So, you have to solve this set of ODEs.

First, consider $\quad\frac{dy}{y(2y+z^2)} =\frac{dz}{z^3}\quad$ Solving it leads to $\quad y=\frac{z^2}{c_1z+2}$
$$\frac{z}{y}-\frac{2}{z}=c_1$$

Second, consider $\frac{dx}{2x(y+z^2)}=\frac{dz}{z^3}$
$$\frac{dx}{2x\left(\frac{z^2}{c_1z+2}+z^2\right)}=\frac{dz}{z^3} \quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{x}-\frac{2(c_1z+3)dz}{(c_1z+2)z}=0$$
$\ln|x|-3\ln|z|+\ln|c_1z+2|=\text{constant}\quad\to\quad x\frac{c_1z+2}{z^3}=c_2$

With $(c_1z+2)=\frac{z^2}{y}$
$$\frac{x}{yz}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is :
$$F\left(\left(\frac{x}{yz}\right)\:,\:\left(\frac{z}{y}-\frac{2}{z}\right)\right)=0$$
which is the expected equation.